# PHP Regex replace everything that isn't a lot of characters

Tags: php, regex, replace, preg-replace

I need a preg-replace function to replace everything that isn't:

```
a-zA-Z0-9 .,:;!?()~=+-_\/@$#&%'"
```

I'm terrible at regular expressions so I have no idea how to escape things that need to be and whatnot. Thanks in advance though!

Oh, by the way, I'm looking to replace it with nothing, just to be clear about that

Comment: *"I'm terrible at regular expressions"* isn't a good excuse not to make the effort to learn. Don't rely on other people to do your work for you! Try to do it yourself and post the code you tried with an explanation if you can't get it to work.

Comment: Why are you doing this simple character removal with regular expressions? Especially that you're terrible with them?

Comment: I'm making a site for someone else that can send text messages, but the service will not allow certain characters to be sent, so that character set is exactly what they gave me. I've tried learning regex but it was about midnight and I just wanted to get it done with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start playing with regex is http://gskinner.com/RegExr/  I find that most of the time if i just play around a bit here that I am able to find exactly what im looking for.  For you example, you might try something like.

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9 .,:;!?()~=+_\\/@$#&%\'"-]
```

Putting this in the RegExr shows that nothing is selected, however if you put in a "*" somewhere in the body, it will select that letter.  This is a great sandbox for regex.  You may also check out the site http://www.regular-expressions.info/ which has some great information on it.

In the question you ask you would use something like:

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 .,:;!?()~=+_\\/@$#&%\'"-]/', "", $string);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually it does work.  Have you tried it?  if you run the following you get the expected:
$string = 'hello * world * !';

print preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 .,:;!?()~=+_\\/@$#&%\'"-]/', "", $string); 

it will return
hello world ! ] - test

Comment: That's not the regex in your answer, above.  Your first regex has the - in the middle, making a range of `[+-_]`.  The error may be forgiven by your regex parser, but it's still an error.  Per [re_format()](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format), "*To include a literal '-', make it the first or last character, or the second endpoint of a range.*"

Comment: Thank you ghoti,  I am sorry that I missed the first part when making the edit to the second part.  I just copied and pasted from the initial question and did not change it both places after i edited my answer.  The change reflects the correct regex.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to escape things.

```
preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 .,:;!?()~=+_\\/@$#&%\'"-]/', "", $string);
```